# Not Returning List of pyodbc Drivers

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am trying to get a list of my installed pyodbc drivers and it is coming back blank.  I am running the following code to get the list:

```
import pyodbc
for driver in pyodbc.drivers():
    
    print (drivers)
```

If it makes any difference I am using a Mac and I have Python 3.8 installed.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you mean `print(driver)` instead of driver**s**?

Comment: Yes, I guess I did typo in my code but changing it to ``print(driver)`` still does not return anything.

Comment: Do you have drivers installed?

Comment: I should. I installed pyodbc with conda.  Is there more that I need to install?

Comment: @Jerel - pyodbc is just the DBAPI interface to communicate with ODBC drivers. You also need to install the particular ODBC driver for the database you will be using. For example, if you were going to be manipulating a Microsoft SQL Server database you would install the "ODBC Driver … for SQL Server" as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: I had also done the ODBC Driver install and just ran it again.  Still nothing.